# Meteor Iron Router. One Route, Multiple Templates. How?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm using the latest Meteor and Iron Router.  Imagine have a 'customComputer' collection.  Computers have three different states: 'ordering', 'building', 'shipped'.

Right now, I'm using three different routes for this, each with a different template

```
/o/_id
/b/_id
/s/_id
```

A computer can't be in 2 states at once, so I'd like to have one route.  How do I wrangle the templates?

```
/c/_id
```

The best I can come up with is to make a "main" template that links to the others.  Is this a best practice?

```
{{#if isOrder}}{{>orderTemplate}}{{/if}}
{{#if isBuilding}}{{>buildingTemplate}}{{/if}}
{{#if isShipped}}{{>shippedTemplate}}{{/if}}
```

Or [dynamic templates](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/)

Here's the route:

```
Router.route('order', {
  path: '/o/:b/:computerId',
  onAfterAction: function() {
    if (this.title) document.title = this.title;
  },
  data: function() {
    if(!this.ready()) return;

    var o = Computer.findOne(this.params.computerId);
    if(!o) throw new Meteor.Error('Computer not found');

    return o;
  },
  waitOn: function() {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) return this.next();  // Don't subscribe if not logged in.
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('computerById', this.params.computerId),
      Meteor.subscribe('myProfile'),
    ];
  },
});
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: the best you have come up with looks reasonable to me.  Is something not working as you like with this approach?

Comment: Thanks, I implemented both and settled on the dynamic template.  It felt like the wrong place for it but no big deal.  I was concerned about performance loading all three templates at the same time, but this seems like how we do it :-)

Comment: How much performance difference was there between the two implementations?  Given that only one if statement will be true, you still only load and render one template. I wouldn't expect any significant performance difference between the two.

Comment: @JeremyK they seem the same, but I'm not stressing them for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do your main template idea, or the dynamic template.

dynamic template tends to be better when you have quite a few options that can be dynamically configured.

But the main template I think ends up being more obvious when you only have a couple of choices.

Either way can be converted easily to the other if you think you need the other option.